# Check if a variable is SRE_Match

Tags: python, regex

I need to check if a variable is a regular expression match object.

`print(type(m))` returns something like that: `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000345BE68>`

but when I import `_sre` and try to execute `type(m) is SRE_Match` the exception `NameError: name 'SRE_Match' is not defined` is raised.

Comment: Normally you only get match objects from functions that either return `None` or a match object...so what's the problem in just testing for `None`?

Comment: I have a dictionary with values of different types and depending on a value type need to perform different actions.

Comment: Ugly datastructures go hand in hand with ugly code

Comment: What exactly is ugly in a dictionary that has values with different types?

Comment: What else is in that dictionary besides regex matches? It really seems like there's a larger design problem...

Comment: Alright, there is a class with overridden `__getattr__` method that returns values from the specific dictionary. If a dictionary value is a match object it returns value of the named group that has a name equal to a dictionary key name, otherwise it just returns a dictionary value.

Comment: `d.update(match.groupdict())` seems to be a better way to just store the match results right away, rather than stuffing a match object into each key...

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
SRE_MATCH_TYPE = type(re.match("", ""))
```

at the start of the program, and then

```
type(m) is SRE_MATCH_TYPE
```

each time you want to make the comparison.

Comment: Does it? With the exception of the line you have to run only once, it's not particularly any more characters than your `type(m) is SRE_Match` solution. And when you try to do something unusual (mixing regular expression results in a dictionary with many other types of values) your code to deal with it sometimes also has to get a bit unusual.

Comment: In that case, what is "dirty" about it?

Comment: IMHO it is about to execute match method to get the type. Anyway, it's only my personal perception.

Comment: I agree that this looks like a hack, but there isn't another way to get a reference to the type because it is defined internally in _sre and not exposed from there. There will be soon though: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0b5e61ddca73ad4fe597fb15065115b0285c8849 which contains this addition to the re module: Match = type(sre_compile.compile('', 0).match('')). Obviously that's the exact same thing, but at least it's hidden in the module!

Answer (score 2):

Pile-on, since there's a whole bunch of ways to solve the problem:

```
def is_match_obj(m):
    t = type(m)
    return (t.__module__, t.__name__) == ('_sre', 'SRE_Match')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from typing import Match

isinstance(m, Match)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
isinstance(m, type(re.match("","")))
```

Usually there is no need to check the type of match objects, so noone has bothered to make a nice way to do it

Comment: @nneonneo, It's really not that hard to work out to assign it to a variable if you are using it often

Answer (score 0):

As `type(m)` returns a printable representation I would use:

```
repr(type(m)) == "<type '_sre.SRE_Match'>"
```

so you don't have to import the `_sre` module and don't have to do any additional `match` call.

That is for Python 2. It seems than in Python 3 the result of type(m) is different, something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000345BE68>`. If so I suppose you can use:

```
repr(type(m)).startswith("<_sre.SRE_Match")
```

or something similar (I don't have a Python 3 interpreter at hand right now, so this part of the answer can be inaccurate.).

Comment: Sadly, not portable to Python 3: `repr(type(m)) == "<class '_sre.SRE_Match'>"`

Comment: Does the question refers to Python 3?

Comment: Yes, he uses `print(type(m))` (Just a guess.)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Python 3.

Comment: OK, but _usually_ `print` with brackets means Python 3. Again, *I'm only guessing*. (And pointing out that the string is different in Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize that the strings are different. I've tried to include Python 3 in my answer.