# Find regular expression type in python

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a variable is SRE_Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506926/check-if-a-variable-is-sre-match)

I need to determine if the parameter passed to a function is a regular expression match type or not. Currently I have:

```
re_type = type(re.compile(''))

def func(result):
    if isinstance(result, re_type):
        print("re")
```

However, I can never get it to print re. When I print result, I get:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fed5330>
```

Is there an easier way to recognize this object?

Comment: @mgilson: that is for patterns, this is for matches (even though the OP got the two mixed up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change first line to:

```
re_type = type(re.match('', ''))
```

Currently you have the re_type set to the type of a regular expression, not the match that results from the application of a regular expression to input.

Note also that the re module will return None where there is no match, so if your function really only expects a match type or None, you might just do:

```
def func(result):
   if result:
      # do stuff...
```

Lastly, you may be violating the [EAFP principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) of Python. This last version assumes result is a match type unless something breaks...

```
def func(result):
    try:
        for group in result.groups():
            # handle match group
    except AttributeError:
       # Looks like this wasn't a real match object
```